# Simple congruence problem

Tags: nt.number-theory

In a paper the author makes a statement which, I think, can only be true if the following holds for all $a,b,m\in\mathbb N$:

If $ab\equiv 1\mod(m^2\ )$, then $a\equiv b\mod (m)$.

Can somebody tell me whether this is true and where I find a proof?

Comment: $m=10$, $a=3$, $b=67$.

Comment: The counterexample in my previous comment and the next few that occurred to me had $a=\pm b \pmod m$, but then I found $m=7$, $a=5$, $b=10$.

Comment: It is as false as I can imagine. For any $a$ coprime to $m$ we get unique residue $c$ mod $m$ such that $ac\equiv 1 \pmod m$, for this $c$ there exist $k$ such that $a(c+mk)\equiv 1 \pmod {m^2}$, and this $b=c+mk$ satisfies $a\equiv b\pmod m$ only if $a^2-1=a(a-c)+(ac-1)$ is divisible by $m$. Unless $m$ divides 24, there exist $a$ coprime to $m$ for which this is not true.

Comment: The claim in the paper I was reading is false, too.